# addClass to child element on click only parent element and not child element itself?

Tags: jquery

I would like to add class to child element of a parent element on click parent element. That is not so exciting..

```
$('.parent').click(function(){
    $(this).children().addClass('newClass');
});
```

However, I don't want to add 'newClass' to child element on click child element itself... is that possible?

Exp: http://jsfiddle.net/qxz1bLt8/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try to use multiple selector at this context,</strike>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.parent,.parent >').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.parent').children().addClass('newClass');
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qxz1bLt8/2/)

Sorry i misunderstood the question, Try to check the target element has a class child or not. If not add the class to it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.parent').click(function (e) {
        $(this).children().toggleClass('newClass', !$(e.target).hasClass(".child"));
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qxz1bLt8/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `target` property of the event. In that you have information about the clicked element:

```
$('.parent').click(function(event){
    if($(event.target).hasClass('parent')) {
        $(this).children().addClass('newClass');
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/) to check if [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) is not `child` then add class.

> `event.target`: The DOM element that initiated the event.

*Use*

```
$('.parent').click(function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.child') == false) {
        $(this).children().addClass('newClass');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/uw6z8zxq/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that works but I think that I found a better solution : e.stopPropagation

Comment: @Mar, You can also do that, in that scenario you need to bind event with child also.

Comment: That's right..the reason I would not like to use event.target because I have ever faced with ie issues using event.target.